# Is it possible for a window to retain a window.opener reference without having been opened by window.open()?

Tags: javascript, browser, window, window.opener

I'm wondering if it is possible in the newer versions of JavaScript (I'm using React ES6, if that factors in at all) for a script in a window to have a `window.opener` where `window.opener !== null`, without having first been opened by the same script using the `open()` command? That's a confusing question so let me try to clarify.

I am currently experiencing a console error in my JS application (run in Chrome) that reads: `Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.` I've seen many questions on SO detailing workarounds for using `window.close()` on a window that wasn't opened by the current script, but that's not quite my question. My code reads:

```
if (window.opener) {
  window.close();
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

`window.close()` is, as far as I know, the only function which can generate this browser error `Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.` But I also would have thought that if there were a non-null reference to `window.opener`, the same script I'm running must have been the opener of the current window. So, how is `window.close()` erroring out, saying that this script didn't open the window, but there's a `window.opener` reference which is non-null?

Comment: Have you tried looking at `window.opener.toString()` or `JSON.stringify(window.opener, null, 2)`?

Comment: Well I'm well aware that there is a reference to `window.opener` -- I don't need to confirm that with `.toString()`. The conditional above wouldn't pass if that weren't the case. What I need to know now is how `window.close()` errors out as it does, but there is a non-null `window.opener`

Comment: I guess it was a suggestion to peek at the reference that was set to help trobleshoot why it's not null/undefined.

Comment: Ah, yes. Well, sadly I can't reproduce the error at the moment. This is why I'm just wondering hypothetically how this could occur, if it can at all.

Comment: `window.opener` will be set if the window was open by an element with `target="_blank"`, eg an anchor or form that has that set

Comment: So it's possible that `target="_blank"` was invoked by some other script in another (or the same?) window? If so, that would explain why `window.close()` is resulting in an error but the conditional passes.